# How would I pivot this basic table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

[image]

What I want is this:

```
visit_id   atc_1   atc_2    atc_3     atc_4     atc_5  atc_6  atc_7
48944282   A02AG   J01CA04  J095AX02  N02BE01   R05X   NaN    NaN
48944305   A02AG   A03AX13  N02BE01      R05X   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I don't know how many atc_1...atc_7...?atc_100 columns there will need to be in advance.  I just need to gather all associated `atc_codes` into one row with each `visit_id`.

This seems like a `group_by` and then a `pivot` but I have tried many times and failed.  I also tried to self-join a la SQL using pandas' `merge`() but that doesn't work either.

The end result is that I will paste together `atc_1`, `atc_7`, ... `atc_100` to form one long `atc_code`.  This composite `atc_code` will be my "`Y`" or "labels" column of my dataset that I am trying to predict.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) first for count values per groups which create columns by function [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html). Then add missing columns with [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and change column names by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html). Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
g = df.groupby('visit_id').cumcount() + 1
print (g)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    4
dtype: int64

df = pd.pivot(index=df['visit_id'], columns=g, values=df['atc_code'])
       .reindex_axis(range(1, 8), 1)
       .add_prefix('atc_')
       .reset_index()

print (df)
   visit_id  atc_1    atc_2     atc_3    atc_4 atc_5  atc_6  atc_7
0  48944282  A02AG  J01CA04  J095AX02  N02BE01  R05X    NaN    NaN
1  48944305  A02AG  A03AX13   N02BE01     R05X  None    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: it is safe to say that whether in 4 minute or 40 years, I would have never been able to come up with this.  Thank you even if I don't fully understand it (yet)

Comment: Give me a sec, I add explanation.